# Raspberry pi 3 set and forget

Tags: mining

I want to setup a raspberry pi 3, then forget about it. Which software can I use that had an auto update feature or setting up a cron job to update the software?  The reasoning is in case there is a vulnerability that needs to be patched a few months after I set it up.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

If you get the daemon up and running after building it then you could just write a script to run git pull and check if there's any updates and if so rebuild then restart the daemon. Or similarly if you're just downloading a binary check the hash of the binary file every day or week to see if it's changed, and if so download new version, stop old one, and start new version. I don't think there's an easy out of the box solution for this though, probably going to have to kind of roll your own.